# Field \"songs\" must not have a selection since type \"[String!]!\" has no subfields

Tags: graphql

I'm getting the above error when doing a query on GraphQL. I found this post which describes my issue, but the suggested answer mentions doing what I'm already doing in my code (Appending createSong with : Song).

Am I misunderstanding the solution, or what am I doing wrong here?

This is my mutation:

```
mutation {
  createSong(songInput: {song_file_name: "test name", song_type: "test type", song_size: 1414, user_name: "user name"}) {
   song_file_name
   song_type
  }
}
```

And this is my query which returns the error.

```
query {
  songs {
    song_file_name
  }
}
```

And here is the code.

````
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql')
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql')

const app = express()

const songs = []

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: buildSchema(`
type Song {
_id: ID!
song_file_name: String!,
song_type: String!,
song_size: Int!,
user_name: String!,
}

input SongInput {
song_file_name: String!
song_type: String!
song_size: Int!
user_name: String!
}

type RootQuery {
songs: [String!]!
}

type RootMutation {
createSong(songInput: SongInput): Song
}

schema {
query: RootQuery
mutation: RootMutation
}
        `),
    rootValue: {
      songs: () => {
        return songs
      },
      createSong: (args) => {
                const song = {
                    _id: Math.random().toString(),
                    song_file_name: args.songInput.song_file_name,
                    song_type: args.songInput.song_type,
                    song_size: +args.songInput.song_size,
                    user_name: args.songInput.user_name
                }
                songs.push(song)
                return song
      },
    },
    graphiql: true,
  })
)

app.listen(3000)
```graph
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created song type and need to pass in your root query it will work for you.

```
type RootQuery {
songs: [Song!]!
}
```